# Autodock Vina Error on Chimera: Service "local" unavailable

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, docking

I was confronted with an error, upon trying to dock a minimized ligand to a target protein, that the "`service 'local' [is] unavailable`". I then realized that one must have an executable file to perform a local docking. **What steps must I take to do this? Is there a file I must download somewhere?**

Comment: Hi Mas! Did you figure this out? Do you have any update for us since January?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.